# How to update status with myspace python api

Tags: python, api, myspace

I'm using myspace python api to post update status, but its return 401, Can't figure it out ,How to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP 401](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html) status code suggests that you need some credentials to perform that POST operation.